# Upcasting a pointer to data member and its polymorphic behavior

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to cast a pointer to data member of derived class to a pointer to data member of  base class, but the following code does not compile:

```
class Base 
{
public:
    virtual void f() {}
};

class Derived : public Base 
{
public:
    void f() override {}
};

class Enclosing
{
public:
    Derived member;
};

int main()
{
    Derived Enclosing::*p = &Enclosing::member;
    auto bp = static_cast<Base Enclosing::*>(p); // compile error
}
```

So I used `reinterpret_cast` instead, and the code compiles:

```
auto bp = reinterpret_cast<Base Enclosing::*>(p); // passes compile
```

And I tried to use `bp` straightforwardly:

```
Enclosing instance;
(instance.*bp).f(); // calls Base::f
```

This is not what I expected because the member in `Enclosing` is actually `Derived` type.
Then I tried this:

```
(&(instance.*bp))->f(); // calls Derived::f
```

It works on my environment, but is this behavior guaranteed?

Comment: This looks like a strict aliasing violation, but the manifestation of UB was "does what you (erroneously) thought was required"

Answer (score 4):

You cannot have what you want. You can get polymorphism with data members only in this situation: `pointer to member of D of type T` converted to `pointer of member of B of type T` where `B` is a base class of `D`.

What you want, converting `pointer to member of X of type T1` to `pointer to member of X of type T2` is not allowed or Undefined Behavior.

To achieve polymorphism you need something like this:

```
Enclosing e;
Derived Enclosing::* d = &Enclosing::d;

Base* b = &(e.*d);
return b->foo();    // calls Derived::foo
```

---

> ## §4 Standard conversions [conv]
>
> Standard conversions are implicit conversions with built-in meaning.
>
> ### §4.11 Pointer to member conversions [conv.mem]
>
> 1. A null pointer constant (4.10) can be converted to a pointer to member type. [...]
> 2. A prvalue of type “pointer to member of B of type cv T”, where B is a class type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to member
>      of D of type cv T”, where D is a derived class (Clause 10) of B. [...]

So we see that for standard conversion (implicit conversions) your conversion is not allowed

> ### §5.2.9 Static cast [expr.static.cast]
>
> 12. A prvalue of type “pointer to member of D of type cv1 T” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to member of B” of type cv2 T,
>       where B is a base class (Clause 10) of D, if a valid standard
>       conversion from “pointer to member of B of type T” to “pointer to
>       member of D of type T” exists (4.11), and cv2 is the same
>       cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, cv1. [...]

For `static_cast` we see that basically only the standard conversion are allowed for pointer to member casts. Which is what you observed, the `static_cast` is a compiler error.

> ### § 5.2.10 Reinterpret cast [expr.reinterpret.cast]
>
> A prvalue of type “pointer to member of X of type T1” can be
>   explicitly converted to a prvalue of a different type “pointer to
>   member of Y of type T2” if T1 and T2 are both function types or both
>   object types. [...]. The result of this conversion is unspecified,
>   except in the following cases:
>
> (10.1) converting a prvalue of type “pointer to member function” to a
>   different pointer to member function type and back to its original
>   type yields the original pointer to member value.
>
> (10.2) converting a prvalue of type “pointer to data member of X of
>   type T1” to the type “pointer to data member of Y of type T2” (where
>   the alignment requirements of T2 are no stricter than those of T1) and
>   back to its original type yields the original pointer to member value.

For `reinterpret_cast` we see the cast is allowed (as you've seen there is no compiler error. However the result is **unspecified**, except in the 2 mentioned cases which imply converting back to the original value. It doesn't apply to our situation, which means that your code with `reinterpret_cast` has Undefined Behavior.

Furthermore

> ### §5.5 Pointer-to-member operators [expr.mptr.oper]
>
> Abbreviating pm-expression .*cast-expression as E1.*E2, E1 is called
>   the object expression . If the dynamic type of E1 does not contain the
>   member to which E2 refers, the behavior is undefined.

This is proof that `instance.*bp` is valid iff the object pointed by `bp` must exist in instance. That implies the type of `bp`.